# How to get enviroment variables injected via -e key in entrypoint script?

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I need to launch my app on the port, set via -e key in `docker run` command

I run my app in `ENTRYPOINT` script and try to get `$PORT` env variable, but there no any env variable, set via -e keys.

Serving the app in Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

func start --port $PORT
```

Docker run command:

```
docker run -d -p 20937:8081 --name queue_0_middleware -e WEBSITE_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=https://functions.azure.com,https://functions-staging.azure.com,https://functions-next.azure.com -e PORT=8081
```

Comment: How exactly do you try to run your docker-container? Could you add the command?

Comment: @sergkondr, sure. Just have added. thank you!

Comment: Your run command appears to be missing an image name.

Comment: @BMitch, Actually, it doesn't. It is an azure launching command got from logs and it identifies necessary image by  ```--name queue_0_middleware``` command

Comment: What happens if you run that exact command outside of the azure launcher?

Comment: @BMitch, If I run this command locally I add image name like this: ```sudo docker run -p 15615:8081 30c7bb13d4b4 --name queue_2_middleware -e PORT=8081```

Answer (score 0):

> If I run this command locally I add image name like this: `sudo docker run -p 15615:8081 30c7bb13d4b4 --name queue_2_middleware -e PORT=8081`

That won't do what you expect, the docker command line is order sensitive. Everything after the image name is used to replace the value of `CMD` inside your image. With the entrypoint defined, those are just args to your entrypoint script. In other words, the docker command looks like:

```
docker run ${args_to_run} ${image_name} ${cmd_override}
```

The fix is to reorder your command with the args to `run` placed before the image name:

```
sudo docker run -p 15615:8081 --name queue_2_middleware -e PORT=8081 30c7bb13d4b4
```